# Changing characters in a string (Path) Java

Tags: java, string

Hello i'm working on program in java, i have a string (a path) in which i want to change the "\" with the "/".

This my program, but i keep having the same path, no changes.

```
package Test;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class Filechooser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFileChooser fc=new JFileChooser();
        fc.setApproveButtonText("Open");
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        fc.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("text Documents", "txt"));
        fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);
        int returnVal=fc.showSaveDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        String path= fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(path); 
        String temp = path.replaceAll("\"", "/");
        System.out.println(temp); 
    }

}
```

Comment: You're replacing the " character, not the \ character. Change it to `"\\\\"` instead of `"\""`. You need three escaping backslashes to cater for the fact that replaceAll accepts a regex argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
String temp = path.replace("\\", "/");
```

`replaceAll(str, str)` takes a regex, not a simple char/string, so you can't use replaceAll like that.

`\\` means `\` in Java, while `\"` means `"`, so be careful with that :)

Comment: Use \\\\ instead of \\ (my initial comment didn't take the fact that it's a regex into consideration)

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your line is that you're replacing `\"` and not `\\` And this `\"` is probably not found at all in your String so nothing changes.

Change this line `String temp = path.replaceAll("\"", "/");`

To this line `String temp = path.replace("\\", "/");` and it should work.

EDIT: As reminded in the comments, using `replaceAll` does not work because it takes a Regex. So you want to use `replace()` which does the exact same thing without the need for Regex.

Comment: To help him understand, I'll just add that ` \ ` is a special char in regex and has to be escaped.

Comment: @Codebender whoops sorry, completely missed that point, edit on its way. Thanks for noticing

Comment: For regexes you escape it to \\\\, so you can use `.replaceAll("\\\\", "/")`

Comment: @JonK changed my answer to include the use of replace() instead, which does not use regexes and thus you do not need to escape at all.

Comment: It's a confusing state of affairs when the main difference between `replace` and `replaceAll` is simply that one accepts a regex and one doesn't...

Comment: @JonK well the replace method may also be a bit faster :)

Comment: I was more coming from a naming convention point-of-view. There's nothing in the naming of `replaceAll` (or `replace`) to suggest that the difference between `replace` and `replaceAll` is that one is regex and one isn't. If anything, someone unfamiliar with them might assume that `replace` does one instance of the occurrence while `replaceAll` does all of them. That said, I prefer your answer anyway because regex is voodoo.

Comment: @JonK oh yeah sure I completely agree with you, the naming here is really poor and unless you're aware of the replaceFirst() function then you can't really guess that replace will also replace all occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

Using [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

`str.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");`

Answer (score -2):

You can not add "\" character to a String object.
but for replace a char with another char you can use this code:

```
 int index = str.indexOf("#");
 String result = str.substring(0,index) + "*" +  str.substring(index+1,str.length());
```

Comment: Why would you do this instead of `replaceAll`?